# How to Parse this XML String?

Tags: php, xml

Even after going through too many posts, I couldn't find a way to parse this XML in PHP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <SingleResponse xmlns="http://content.host.com">
         <ContentCafe DateTime="2013-02-18T04:31:16.1619171-05:00">
            <RequestItems UserID="abcdefg" Password="hijklmnop">
               <RequestItem>
                  <Key Type="ISBN" Original="9780002571838">9780002571838</Key>
                  <Content>ProductDetail</Content>
                  <ProductItems>
                     <ProductItem ID="8714731">
                        <ISBN>9780002571838</ISBN>
                        <Title>Memoirs</Title>
                        <Author>Rees-Mogg, William</Author>
                        <Source Code="BTB">B&amp;T Books</Source>
                        <Product Code="BOOK">Book</Product>
                        <Supplier Code="HARPE">HarperCollins</Supplier>
                     </ProductItem>
                  </ProductItems>
               </RequestItem>
            </RequestItems>
         </ContentCafe>
      </SingleResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I came until this point:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

but don't know how to proceed further reading the `Title`, `Author` and other information. Greatly appreciate any help that you could provide.

Comment: can you use `xml_parse_into_struct()`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I went over that post but didn't quite understand the step `$res = $client->SoapFunction(array('param1'=>'value','param2'=>'value'));`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

[Demo](http://codepad.org/8l6RBqfx)

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$item = $obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->children()->SingleResponse->ContentCafe->RequestItems->RequestItem->ProductItems->ProductItem;

echo $item->Title . "\n";
echo $item->Author . "\n";
echo $item->attributes()->ID;
```

Outputs

> Memoirs
>   Rees-Mogg, William
>   8714731

If you have multiple `<ProductItem>` you will have to loop them instead of directly accessing them as I have done.

Comment: Very simple and straight to the point. Thanks a lot for teaching this!

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you can use  **[SOAP Client `getTypes ()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.gettypes.php)** to fetch the struct and then design the code to handle the string returned from  `doRequest()` method.

I guess, you should not be treating the response from a Webservice in terms of serialized XML data. Instead, use standard APIs to wrap it and just consider it as calling an API functional call. And process the return data rather than processing the entire HTTP packet data.

These resources might help . See this [IBM's tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/) and also the [PHP Soap Client Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Those links look really useful!